WebkitSpeechRecognition implementation to identical to Google offering
Basically, I am trying to mimick exactly what Google offers with their Webspeech Api however, I keep running into the issue where as soon as I stop talking the transcribed message from earlier disappears and then also when i click stop recording it just reverts to record for a split second and then stop recording again. Please help me fix this. Here is acess to my index and main files.
Main.tsx:
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import useSpeechToText from '../hooks';

const Main = () => {
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');

    const {isListening, transcript, startListening, stopListening} = useSpeechToText({continous:true})

    const startStopListening = () => {
        isListening ? stopVoiceInput() : startListening()
    }

    const stopVoiceInput = () => {
        setTextInput(prevVal => prevVal + (transcript.length ? (prevVal.length ? ' ' : '') + transcript : ''))
        stopListening()
    }




    return(
        <div style={{display:'block', margin:'0 auto', width:'400px', textAlign:'center', marginTop:'200px'}}>
            <button
            onClick={() => {startStopListening()}}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: isListening ? "#d62d20" : "#008744",
                color: "white", 
                padding: "10px 20px",
                border: 'none',
                borderRadius: '5px',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                transition: 'background-colo 0.3s ease',
            }}>
            {isListening? 'Stop listening' : 'Listen'}
            </button>
            <textarea
                style={{
                    marginTop: '20px',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '150px',
                    padding: '10px',
                    border: '1px solid #ccc',
                    borderRadius: '5px',
                    transition: 'border-color 0.3s ease',
                    resize: 'none',
                    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
                    color: '#333',
                }}
                disabled={isListening}
                value ={isListening ? textInput + (transcript.length ? (textInput.length ? ' ' : '') + transcript: '') : textInput}
                onChange={(e)=>{setTextInput(e.target.value)}}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main

index.jsx:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useSpeechToText = (options) => {
        const [isListening, setIsListening] = useState(false)
        const [transcript, setTranscript] = useState("")
        const [noReason, setNoReason] = useState(true);
        const recgonitionRef = useRef(null)

        useEffect(()=>{
            if(!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)){
                console.error("Web speech api is not supported")
                return; 
            }

            recgonitionRef.current = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition()
            const recognition = recgonitionRef.current
            recognition.interimResults = options.interimResults || true
            recognition.lang = "en-US"
            recognition.continous = true

            if("webkitSpeechGrammarList" in window){
                const grammar = "#JSFG V1.0; grammar punctuation; public <punc> = . | , | ? | ! | ; | : ;"
                const speechRecognitionList = new window.webkitSpeechGrammarList()
                speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1)
                recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList
            }

            recognition.onresult = (event) => {
                let text = ""
                for (let i=0; i<event.results.length; i++){
                    text += event.results[i][0].transcript
                }
                setTranscript(text)
                setNoReason(false)
            }

            recognition.onerror = (event) => {
                console.error("Speech recognition error:", event.error)
            }

            recognition.onend = () =>{
                if (noReason) {
                    // If there was no reason for ending, restart the recognition
                    recgonitionRef.current.start();
                    setIsListening(true);
                    setNoReason(true);  // Reset for the new session
                }
            }

            return () => {
                recognition.stop()
            }
        }, [])

        const startListening = () =>{
            if (recgonitionRef.current && !isListening){
                recgonitionRef.current.start()
                setIsListening(true)
                setNoReason(true)
            }
        }

        const stopListening = () =>{
            if (recgonitionRef.current && isListening){
                recgonitionRef.current.stop()
                setIsListening(false);
            }
        }

    return {
        isListening,
        transcript,
        startListening,
        stopListening
    }
}

export default useSpeechToText

I have tried a bunch of little things but cant get it to work.
